# What is the latest version of google play services which FlurryAnalytics 5.5 is compatible with?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, flurry

In an Android Studio project, I'm trying to use FlurryAnalytics 5.5 with Google Play Services 7.5.0. They compile, but one thing does not work: though the FlurryAgent records my custom events, it never quite seems to send them up to the server.

That is, I do see plenty of log messages like these:

- FlurryAgent: Flurry session resumed for context ...
- FlurryAgent: Event count started ...

After my app is put into the background, although I see this in the log:

- FlurryAgent: Flurry session ended

I never quite see this in the log:

- FlurryAgent: analytics report sent

So, Flurry info never makes it from my app up to the Flurry servers.

I've tried using various other versions of Google Play Services library with Flurry 5.5, but the latest one I can find that seems to allow the Flurry event data to make it up to the server is:

- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87

I would really prefer to use:

- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0

because I would also like to use the latest Google Cloud Messaging facilities.

So -- is there a way to use Flurry 5.5 (or any other Flurry version) with Google Play Services 7.5.0 and actually see the data go up to the Flurry servers? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: The Flurry SDK works with 7.5.0 and I see "Analytics report sent" in logs. Maybe you could try other devices and make sure the device itself has GPS 7.5.0+

Comment: Thank you. I can now see that you are correct. My app has some other problem which I have not figured out. Again, thank you for your answer and for ruling that out. Cheers.

Comment: Hey @albertbraun I've ran into the same issue lately but no luck yet. Have you managed to fix the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have not had time to fix this. Honestly, I moved away from Flurry to a different mobile analytics provider (AWS). If I have more time to work on this and if I am lucky enough to find a workaround, I will post it here. Once again, sorry I do not have a better answer.