# Flurry analytics 5.6.0 not sending events to Flurry servers

Tags: android, google-play-services, flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm new to Flurry but I've implemented the SDK based on the official documentation, and it seems to be "working". Sessions are started correctly and events are tracked but never ever sent to server. What am I missing?

A similar issue has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469030/what-is-the-latest-version-of-google-play-services-which-flurryanalytics-5-5-is)

My project configuration is as follows:

- GooglePlayServices version: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0
- Flurry Version: FlurryAnalytics-5.6.0.jar

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any session data on Flurry dashboard?

Comment: Yes I do see. Events are created and incremented. But not "Flurry data sent to server." or something similar after the session ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely because you are selectively compiling the GooglePlayServices SDK. You are adding only Google Cloud Messaging (gcm) as a dependency. You need to also include the ads module to use Flurry.

That is, if you don't have `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0` (the entire Google Play Services API) in your build.gradle, you should have at least `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0` or `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0`(note the addition of **ads** and **analytics** at the end), in addition to your other dependencies.

After you do this (and you have Flurry DEBUG log enabled), you should see "Analytics report sent" after each new session *begins*.

Comment: Yes @Ugo, good point. I'm not sure about ads though, because I fixed it the day I posted the question with adding the analytics package to my dependencies. I will check if your solution works, and mark the answer afterwards. Thanks for your time. Cheers.

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár, glad to know you've solved the problem, but I'm not quite sure how you did it. Your question implied that you had already added the Flurry analytics package. Out of curiosity, what else did you have to add?

Comment: I was referring to the Google Analytics package (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The `AdvertisingIdClient` which Flurry uses is part of the Google Analytics API. The Google Ads API has the Analytics API as a transitive dependency, so it is better to include the Analytics API directly.